# java.lang.InterruptedException when creating SparkSession in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

If I clone this gist: https://gist.github.com/jamiekt/cea2dab3ea8de91489b31045b302e011

and then issue `sbt run` it fails on the line

```scala
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
                        .config(new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]"))
                        .enableHiveSupport()
                        .getOrCreate()
```

with error:

> Java.lang.InterruptedException
>           at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)

No clue why this might be happening. Anyone got a suggestion?

Scala version is 2.11.12 (see in **build.sbt** in the gist)
Spark version is 2.3.0 (again, see in **build.sbt**)
Java Version

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_161"
```

Comment: thx @RameshMaharjan. I've updated the question with that info.

Comment: I'm still a Scala/sbt newbie so right now I'm not entirely sure what is the correct command to use, though given this is a Scala application `sbt run` seems appropriate. if I comment out that line and instead run something simple like `print("hello world")` then it runs as expected.

Comment: `spark-submit` is for submitting spark  applications(that are written either in java, scala or python) to a spark cluster. That's not what I'm trying to do here, I'm simply using spark as a library to create a spark session and I believe it is valid to do so.

Comment: it's just part of stacktrace, I can't see root cause.

Comment: That's the first error I encounter in the stack trace. Can you reproduce the problem by cloning the repo?

Comment: moreover first line in script.scala says run using `sbt console < script.scala` did you try it?

Comment: ignore that line :) I put that in there, it should be ignored. In fact I've just removed it.

Comment: @jamiet, I have tried to explain the cause below in my answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because you have not stopped the *sparkSession* instance created and the instance is removed from memory without being closed as soon as `sbt run` completes i.e. after the successful completion of your code.

So all you require is

```
  spark.stop()
```

at the end of the scope where the instance is created as

```
object Application extends App{
  import DataFrameExtensions_._
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]")).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
  //import spark.implicits._
  //val df = Seq((8, "bat"),(64, "mouse"),(-27, "horse")).toDF("number", "word")
  //val groupBy = Seq("number","word")
  //val asAt = LocalDate.now()
  //val joinedDf = Seq(df.featuresGroup1(_,_), df.featuresGroup2(_,_)).map(_(groupBy, asAt)).joinDataFramesOnColumns(groupBy)
  //joinedDf.show

  spark.stop()
}
```

Just before the

> > `Java.lang.InterruptedException at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)`

You must have following message too

> > `ERROR Utils: uncaught error in thread SparkListenerBus, stopping SparkContext`

which gives clue to the cause of the error.

Comment: **which clearly states the cause of the error** I might dispute the use of the word "clearly" :) :)